# Is there an escalated support channel for Stack Overflow for Teams?

Tags: support, stack-overflow-for-teams

Our Stack Overflow for Teams instance has had "Oops! Something Bad Happened!" for the last two hours when asking a question. This also occurred yesterday, but at some point resolved.

A support ticket has been raised, but there's only an automatic acknowledgement that the ticket will be addressed within 24 hours.

Stack Exchange status shows a last update in July, and the Stack Exchange Status Twitter account shows nothing.

Even when this issue is resolved, is there a better way to raise urgent issues for something that we'd be paying a not-inconsiderable amount of money for?

Comment: Hey Michael, while I'm not sure on the support side we did see this issue elsewhere and wanted to unblock you. Does the question being asked contain emoji by chance?

Comment: No, this is simply hitting the "ask a question" button, no question is entered.

Comment: Right now I'm much more worried about this happening again (if we commit to SO for teams) and not having a way to escalate critical loss of functionality (eg via a support Slack, etc)

Comment: I'll let Chance answer there - I'm honestly just not sure what the channels are. We noticed your error in the log (not in Teams but outside Teams...which is why alarms didn't sound) and I'm digging into the cause now.

Comment: Michael I'm sorry you're hitting this - while I'm not sure exactly what in the page is causing this to throw (it's a proxy issue - and we'd need authorization to look at any data), the point we're throwing at we can see and we'll try and get a fix out for first thing in the morning (we'll need to carefully test a change here). I've pinged the Teams team on the support question and they'll get back ASAP. While you are the only person hitting this that I can see in our logs, that makes it no less important on our end - we'll get you fixed up as soon as we safely can deploy a fix in the morning.

Comment: Great. How do I raise this and get this kind of information in the future? And what do you mean by "morning"? Whose morning?

Comment: @NickCraver issue is resolved, but the main question still stands. What's important here is communication / notification / ETA rather than the issue itself.

Answer (score 19):

First and foremost, I’m sorry about this issue and I’ve gone ahead and extended your trial another week to give you more time to evaluate Teams.

It looks as though the issue you experienced wasn’t product-wide, but was isolated to your Team. In particular, it was caused by some unicode or emoji.

Regardless, your question is more specifically about our support story. Teams does not currently have a specific SLA, but dependent on the severity of the issue we will respond within no more than 2 business days based on east coast hours of the United States, where our support team is located. However, our support team tends to respond much *much* quicker. In your scenario, our team received the request at about 7:00 pm ET and responded by 5:00 am ET.

teams-support@ or the contact form at https://www.stackoverflow.help/support/home (which you used) is the only mechanism to contact our team.

I totally understand how all of this can be frustrating considering that our support hours don’t currently overlap well with Australia. I’m really sorry about that and understand how that could impact your decision to use Teams. I would note that we do expect in the future to offer different tiers of service and response times that could help remedy this situation. We’re still finalizing details, but it is likely we will be able to address this in the coming 6 months. Don't hesitate to let me know if you have any additional questions!

Comment: Can you share more information - like where the emoji was?  Is it a profile text character issue or something else?

Comment: @JonH We didn't end up requesting authorization to view their data, so we never actually confirmed that this was the issue, let alone exactly where it was. The emoji/unicode is just an informed guess.

Comment: @JonH we've seen the issue in the wild before but it's tough to repro. The affected area of code (and where the exception was thrown) was where we proxy from the secure Teams network and decode the output into a buffer for rendering in the Stack Overflow layout. That decode operation threw with an exception indicating that we had a tear between two buffers when decoding from an array of bytes into an array of UTF8 chars. It generally happens with multibyte UTF8 chars such as emoji, hence the educated guess. It could have been anywhere on the output rendered from Teams.

Comment: Thanks for the honest feedback! If we give you auth would it help you diagnose the problem? I'm also very curious as to which question/answer it was!